# Unix: Copy Command cp

Tags: bash

What is the difference between

```
cp -a Dir NewDir
```

and

```
cp -pr Dir NewDir
```

?

Answer (score 2):

`-a` is equivalent to `-dpr`, which means copy symlinks literally (instead of their targets), preserve mode, ownership and timestamps, and recurse (copy subdirectories)

`-pr` would follow symlinks and copy their targets, instead of physically copying the symlink.  It would still preserve mode, ownership and timestamps, and still recurse.

`man cp` will tell you all you need to know.